# Removing commas from a string using SQL

Tags: sql

If i have the string:

```
[30.345, -97.345, 4],[30.345, -97.345, 5],[30.345, -97.345, 6],[30.345, -97.345, 7]
```

How would i remove every third comma, so that the string would look like this?

```
[30.345, -97.345, 4][30.345, -97.345, 5][30.345, -97.345, 6][30.345, -97.345, 7] ?
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I am working with oracle apex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

how about replacing `],[` with `][`

```
SELECT REPLACE('[30.345, -97.345, 4],[30.345, -97.345, 5],[30.345, -97.345, 6],[30.345, -97.345, 7].','],[','][');
```

Answer (score 2):

sql is to general, need more info.

Here is ORACLE:

select replace('your string', '],[', '][') from dual

Comment: I'm tempted to make a joke about you being an oracle having guessed his db platform correctly, but that would be tacky. ;-) (+1)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the REPLACE MySQL function.

Here is a link to some documentation on how to implement it: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Something like:

```
SELECT REPLACE('[30.345, -97.345, 4],[30.345, -97.345, 5],[30.345, -97.345, 6],[30.345, -97.345, 7]', '],[', '][');
```